# Dynamically adding text input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript and Jquery and trying to learn how to dinamically add 
 elemnts to my html.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Academic Calculator</title>
    <meta name="Calculator" content="Academic Calculator">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Calculate.css">

</head>
<body>
    <script src="CalculatorLogics.js"></script>
    <div>
        <form>
                First Name:<br>
                <input name="first-name">
                <br>
                Last Name:<br>
                <input name="last-name">
                <br>
            <hr>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="courses">
        <button type="button" onclick="createNewCourses()">Add Course</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my Javascript:

```
function createNewCourses() {
    $(".courses").append("<input type='text>");
}
```

Comment: I know there was an edit approved, but it invalidates the answers by fixing the problem. As such, I've filled it back.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a mistake `'text` replace with `"text"`

```js
function createNewCourses() {
    $('.courses').append('<input type="text">');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <div>
        <form>
                First Name:<br>
                <input name="first-name">
                <br>
                Last Name:<br>
                <input name="last-name">
                <br>
            <hr>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="courses">
        <button type="button" onclick="createNewCourses()">Add Course</button>
    </div>
```